# UnsatisfiedLinkError with jNetPcap

Tags: java, api

I recently installed WinPcap and put the jNetPcap dll (jnetpcap.dll) into my system32 folder on Windows. In my run settings of the application I added this: -`Djava.library.path="C:\Windows\System32\jnetpcap.dll"`
and I added the jar file to my project as resource and dependency. To test it I defined this in one of my classes:
`Pcap pcap = new Pcap();` and I added a system path variable (I followed the installation guide which was in the zip file I downloaded of jNetPcap, I also installed WinPcap). But now I am getting this error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Native Method) ~[NativeLibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[NativeLibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[JNILibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) ~[JNILibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source) ~[JNILibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source) ~[JNILibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source) ~[JNILibrary.class:1.4.r1425]
    at org.jnetpcap.Pcap.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[Pcap.class:1.4.r1425]
    at de.herrhass.netsniff.NetSniff.onEnable(NetSniff.java:18) ~[NetSniff.class:?]
    at net.labymod.addon.AddonLoader.enableAddon(AddonLoader.java:349) [AddonLoader.class:?]
    at net.labymod.addon.AddonLoader.enableAddons(AddonLoader.java:309) [AddonLoader.class:?]
    at net.labymod.main.LabyMod.init(LabyMod.java:256) [LabyMod.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:560) [FMLModContainer.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:211) [LoadController.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:189) [LoadController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118) [LoadController.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:737) [Loader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:310) [FMLClientHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:532) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:360) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:116) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26) [start/:?]`